# Regex to split string with varying delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Need some regex help with some complicated string in c#.

The string I have is:

```
-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 1-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3
```

The split I want is this:

**MATCH 1:**

```
-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 1
```

**MATCH 2:**

```
-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2
```

**MATCH 3:**

```
-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3
```

I've tried Regex.Split() based on the pattern to match the string with the dashes(--), but the problem is that I want that as part of the split as well. I'm OK with it giving me the separate matches for the string and the actual comment, along with the -- string, but with this I'm getting duplicates:

```
string input = "-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 1-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3";
string pattern = "((?<=--)(.*)(?=--------------))";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);    // Split on hyphens 
int i = 1;
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Response.Write("MATCH " + i.ToString() + ":" + string.Format("{0}", match) + "<br>");
    i++;
}
```

With this, the output I'm getting is:

```
    MATCH 1:--
    MATCH 2: [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT) Mickey Rahman] 
    MATCH 3: [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT) Mickey Rahman] 
    MATCH 4:-------------- Comment 1 --
    MATCH 5: [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT) Mickey Rahman] 
    MATCH 6: [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT) Mickey Rahman] 
    MATCH 7:-------------- Comment 2 --
    MATCH 8: [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT) Automation User] 
    MATCH 9: [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT) Automation User] 
    MATCH 10:-------------- TEST 3
```

Comment: When using the split method is too complicated, try to use the "Matches" method with the `\G` anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
string input = "-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 1-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3";
string pattern = @"(?=-- \[.+\])";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(_=>_.Length > 0).ToArray();    // Split on hyphens 
int i = 1;
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MATCH " + i.ToString() + ":" + string.Format("{0}", match));
    i++;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
MATCH 1:-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 1
MATCH 2:-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2
MATCH 3:-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are content with using the split method, this is the solution I came up with.

```
String input   = @"-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comm--ent 1-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<!\A)(?=-- *\[)");

int i = 1;
foreach (string m in parts) {
         Console.WriteLine("MATCH " + i + ":" + m); ++i;
}
```

Output

```
MATCH 1:-- [AUG-24-14 11:58 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comm--ent 1
MATCH 2:-- [AUG-24-14 11:40 PM (EDT)  Mickey Rahman] --------------Comment 2
MATCH 3:-- [AUG-22-14 11:51 PM (EDT)  Automation User] --------------TEST 3
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/WLN4Ma)

Comment: Works for the most part - what happens if there is '--' inside the comment - like so: 'comm--ent' is there a way I can maybe split on '--['?